# DBCommand using block

Tags: using, dbcommand

I have the following code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Events";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

From reading a few articles on this site, it is suggested that the `DbCommand` should be in a using block, however, I can't see why this is needed.
The Connection is closed, so what is DbCommand holding on to that requires a using block?
Is it really the case if a class inherits from IDisposable that you **must** use a using block or manually called Dispose?

I ran a simulator with 100 threads on the code above, and also with code with a using block on the `DbCommand` and I could see no real differences in memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

`DbCommand` is abstract, and does not presuppose what native resources the vendor-specific subclass will hold, and in what order they should be released. Proper nesting of `using` blocks seems a reasonable implicit coding convention.

Comment: It would be a MySqlCommand, however, what I am asking is **why** the using statement would be required in this specific example, not why it might be good coding practice. If I don't have the using statement for a MySqlCommand in this example, do I have a resource leak?

Comment: The resource leak, were there one, would be inside the MySQL native API, a `MYSQL_RES` not `mysql_free_result`'d in this case. But it will be. `IDisposable` objects are generally written so that when the object is GC'd, undisposed resources are diposed of.